# При использовании Библиотеки PyTorch(библиотека устонавливалась через conda) Возникает ошибка OSError: [WinError 127]. Как исправить данную ошибку?

Tags: python, anaconda, pytorch, conda

Код программы:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import numpy as np


# Определение архитектуры нейронной сети
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_inputs, num_outputs, num_hidden):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(num_inputs, num_hidden)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(num_hidden, num_outputs)
        self.activation_function = nn.ReLU()

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = self.activation_function(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return x


# Создание тренировочных данных
inputs = np.array([[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]])
outputs = np.array([[0], [1], [1], [0]])

# Создание экземпляра нейронной сети
net = Net(num_inputs=2, num_outputs=1, num_hidden=3)

# Определение функции потерь и оптимизатора
criterion = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=0.1)

# Обучение нейронной сети
for epoch in range(10000):
    # Преобразование входных и выходных данных в тензоры PyTorch
    inputs_tensor = torch.from_numpy(inputs).float()
    outputs_tensor = torch.from_numpy(outputs).float()

    # Прямой проход по нейронной сети
    outputs_pred = net(inputs_tensor)

    # Вычисление функции потерь
    loss = criterion(outputs_pred, outputs_tensor)

    # Обнуление градиентов
    optimizer.zero_grad()

    # Обратное распространение ошибки и вычисление градиентов
    loss.backward()

    # Обновление весов и смещений
    optimizer.step()

# Тестирование нейронной сети
inputs_tensor = torch.from_numpy(inputs).float()
outputs_pred = net(inputs_tensor)
print(outputs_pred)
```

Вывод при компиляции:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Development\Python\AI\AI_Start\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import torch
  File "C:\Users\name\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\__init__.py", line 128, in <module>
    raise err
OSError: [WinError 127] Не найдена указанная процедура. Error loading "C:\Users\name\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\lib\shm.dll" or one of its dependencies.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте поставить `CUDA toolkit`:

```
conda install cudatoolkit
```

Совет взят с [англоязычного СО](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74764638/8324991).